# Non public-API usage,Invalid Binary

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, ipa

Non-public API usage:

> The app contains or inherits from non-public classes in appname:
>   DBManager
>
> If method names in your source code match the private Apple APIs
>   listed above, altering your method names will help prevent this app
>   from being flagged in future submissions. In addition, note that one
>   or more of the above APIs may be located in a static library that was
>   included with your app. If so, they must be removed.

I am trying to upload a build ,but apple is invaliding my binary with above error.

`DBManager` is class used for SQLite operations it doesn't use any private API.

Comment: Maybe DBManager is using some "by apple" classified non public methods of sqlite or something. Did you try using some [scanning tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546046/check-for-private-api-usage-yourself)?  I had the same problem when using non public api's of webkit...

Comment: Maybe a name collision with some apple-internal stuff. You could start to argue with them or (if you are dealing with your own code - seems so-) you could rename DBManager to something else and re-submit.

Comment: So, 9 days later: could you tell us, how thinks worked out for you?

Comment: i got email from Apple that one of file is using private API,I renamed that file and sent ma binary and it was approved.